# ¿Cómo guardar el cambio de color de un botón en Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, vscode

**El programa consiste en clickar un botón y que éste cambie de color. Quisiera que cuando cierre el programa y lo vuelva a abrir siga estando como se quedó **

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
ventana = tkinter.Tk()
ventana.title("Horario")


ventana.geometry("500x200")
ventana.resizable(0,0)
#titulo

def PagadoR1():
    botonR.configure(bg="green",fg="black")
def salir():
    ventana.destroy()

#alumnos
botonR= tkinter.Button(ventana, text="boton",command = PagadoR1)
botonR.pack()
botonR.place(x=70,y=100)

botonsalir= tkinter.Button(ventana, text="Salir",command = salir, fg="blue")
botonsalir.pack()
botonsalir.place(x=250,y=175)


ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: El idioma del sitio es el español. Por favor traduce tu pregunta.

Comment: No existe, en tkinter, una forma de hacerlo. Tendrás que guardar el estado del botón en un archivo al momento de cerrar la ventana y restaurarlo cuando se inicie el programa.